# resignFirstResponder not hiding UIkeyboard in iPad

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikeyboard, resignfirstresponder

I have an iPad application in which resignFirstResponder does't seems to be working.
I have tried many solutions. I am just calling resign first responder from the instance of the  firstResponder object but keyboard is remain there on the screen. THen I tried by iterating all the window to get the instance of the first responder and then I am calling the resignFirstResponder from that instance.

I also try by creating the category of the `UIViewController` for the following methods.

```
  - (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal
    {
         return NO;
    }
```

But this solution is also not working for me. And this keyboard problem is there in all the textfield of application not only for some specific textfield.

Update:
In different part of the app I am using different code for this purpose. Here is the code

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)mtextField
 {
 [mtextField resignFirstResponder]; this one is not required but I have just write   it here.
 }

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
if([string hasSuffix:@"\n"])
{
    [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```

Update: When I try by running the application in  the simulator, some times it `resignFirstResponder` is working, but not on every launch even in simulator.

Comment: It's hard to guess what's going on without seeing the source.  Have you tried calling `endEditing` on your view controller's top-level view?

Comment: I have tried the endEditing on the viewcontroller's view property.

Comment: Shouldn't `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal` return NO if you want the keyboard to dismiss?

Comment: Ok, disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal should return NO. Thats the mistake in the typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this problem. Actually there seems to some change in the apple cocoa API. In my app I have an `UIAlertView`, which we used to display to show that some operation is going on and user should wait to finish it. For that purpose the code I use in my app was

```
- (void)displayAlertView
   {
     UIAlertView *alertView = creating the object;
     UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator= creating the object;
     [alertView addSubview:activityIndicator];
     [activityIndicator startAnimating];
     [alertView show];
     [alertView release];
    }

-(void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
 {
      [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
 }
```

The problem get resolved when I use the code below in my application

```
  -(void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
 {
      [self performSelector:@selector(dismissView:) withObject:alertView afterDelay:0.0];

 }

  -(void)dismissView:(UIAlertView*)alertView
 {
      [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
 }
```

I think here some thing is going wrong in the `UIAlertView`, and because of that keyboard is not hiding when resigning as the first responder.

Answer (score 5):

the simplest and best way to hide the keyboard is to use

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

and make sure you are setting appropriate delegate of the textfields

Comment: It tried this way, but it is not working, keyboard is still on the screen.

Comment: are your fields on separate view within nib ?? if so, call `[thatViewOutlet endEditing:YES];`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the keyboard to resign when you press the return key, you need to use:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField

{
[textField resignFirstResponder];  
return YES;
}
```

*Then* the textFieldDidEndEditing gets invoked.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't call methods in Objective-C, rather you send messages to objects.

`UIView` isn't the one who should send the message `resignFirstResponder`. Have your `UITextField` as a property - let's call it myTextField. You should use this:

```
[self.myTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: WIll it create any difference if I will send message or just call the objective C method. And I have tried by calling it through the property also.

Comment: it's not about creating a difference. I was just talking about how the language worked. What you (I do it a lot too) call "calling a method" is actually sending a message. I'm sorry my answer didn't help